# logic implementation to find the Maximum sum of non consecutive possessive elements of a array

Tags: python, algorithm, logic

their is an array with positive and negative integers 
suppose :1,2,-1,3,5,1,-4,2,7
now i have to find the max sum of all combination

combination should be such that

**1. no elements are consecutive in main set

 2. element should be positive**

initially i thought to implement this by dividing it in even and odds but that is not actually resolving .

```
 ods=[]
 evns=[]
 ok=0;
 ek=1;
 for x in range(n):
            print(str(x)+"-"+str(ok)+"-"+str(ek))
            if x == ok and tkts[x]>0:
                ods.append(tkts[x])
                ok+=2
            elif x == ok and tkts[x] <= 0:
                ok+=1

            if x == ek and tkts[x]>0:
                evns.append(tkts[x])
                ek+=2
            elif x == ek and tkts[x] <= 0:
                ek+=1
```

what should be the logic can one please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DP. The recursive idea is as follows

```
get_max(index):
    max = 0
    for i from index+2 to len:
        if(array[i] > 0)
            v = get_max(i)
            if (v > max) max = v
    return array[index]+max
get_max(0)
```

if we memoize

```
x = [1,2,-1,3,5,1,-4,2,7]
dp = [0]*len(x)
ret = 0
for i in range(len(x)-3, -1, -1):
    max = 0
    for j in range(i+2, len(x)):
        if x[j] > 0 and dp[j]>max: max = dp[j]
    if x[i] > 0:
        dp[i] = max + x[i]
        if ret < dp[i]: ret = dp[i]
```

(I have not tested this code, this is just for the idea)